# Additional capacitors

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

This might be a simple one to answer.

I am using a controller IC (MCP73871) whose load output is connected to an LDO (lm1117Mp3.3). Now according to the datasheet of the MCP73871, I should be adding a capacitor of 4.7uF at the output, while according to lm1117Mp3.3, I need a 10uF capacitor at its input. So is it ok to use both capacitors or just use the one with higher capacity, or it doesn't really matter. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> according to the datasheet of the MCP73871, I should be adding a
>   capacitor of 4.7uF at the output

If you read the data sheet for the MCP73871 on page 17 it says this: -

> Bypass to VSS with a minimum of 4.7 μF is recommended.

This means you can add more and more usually is the safer option in most circuits.

I would probably use a 10 uF for the output and another 10 uF for the LM1117's input.